# Como ignorar parte del fichero en c

Tags: c

necesito saber como ignorar las primeras filas de un txt en c como por ejemplo:

```
AQJAS
KJSA
KSJA
1 2 3
123235
```

en ese ejemplo quiero leer desde el 1 hacia adelante, como puedo ignorar esos caracteres de mas arriba gracias.

Comment: ¿cual es la entrada? ¿es el numero de fila? ¿es que se ignore todas las filas anteriores si no comienzan con 1?, respondeme y explica con mayor detalle, lee [ask] y pasa el [tour]

Comment: yo creo que te refieres a los comentarios. Es así; /* AQJAS
KJSA
KSJA */
1 2 3
123235

Comment: ¿estas segurlo?, el archivo es un .txt, los simbolos `/* */` son solo reconocidos por el compilador

Comment: ¿Cual o cuáles son las reglas que determinan dónde hay que comenzar a leer?

Answer (score 0):

> Necesito saber como ignorar las primeras filas de un txt en C

Si las filas son de una longitud variable (como parece ser tu caso) no puedes ignorarlas: deberás leerlas al completo.

---

En C, los archivos se procesan como un flujo de datos: se coloca un puntero de lectura en una posición y se hace avanzar o retroceder dicho puntero de lectura por el contenido del archivo; es posible avanzar o retroceder cantidades fijas de datos (mediante [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)) pero si los datos a procesar no tienen un tamaño fijo la única manera de distinguir unos datos de otros es leyéndolos.

#### Propuesta.

Deberías leer el archivo de datos línea a línea:

```
char *buffer = NULL;
FILE *archivo = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");

if (archivo)
{
    for (size_t length; archivo && (getline(&buffer, &length, archivo) != -1); )
    {
        // 'buffer' contiene la línea leída.
    }

    fclose(archivo);
}
```

Cuando la línea leída contenga los datos que buscas, empieza a procesar, ignorando el resto, por ejemplo así:

```
void procesa_datos(FILE *entrada, char **buffer)
{
    printf("Empezamos a procesar archivo...\n\n"
           "Datos a procesar: %s", *buffer);
    for (size_t length; entrada && (getline(buffer, &length, entrada) != -1); )
        printf("Datos a procesar: %s", *buffer);
}

int main()
{
    char *buffer = NULL;
    FILE *archivo = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");

    if (archivo)
    {
        for (size_t length; archivo && (getline(&buffer, &length, archivo) != -1); )
        {
            if (isalpha(*buffer)) // El primer carácter es una letra o un número?
                printf("Datos a ignorar: %s", buffer);
            else
                procesa_datos(archivo, &buffer);
        }

        fclose(archivo);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Yo he usado como criterio que el primer carácter de la línea sea un número, tú deberás usar el criterio que te sea conveniente.